# Custom toolbar with Summernote

Tags: toolbar, summernote

How do I know which functions can be enabled for the toolbar of summernote, and how to do it?

In the API docs all I can find is "toolbar : Array (optional)" without further explanation.

I've managed to enable some features thanks to one of the examples, but **how can I also enable: code, indent and outdent?**

```js
$(".summernote").summernote({
    styleWithSpan: false,
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol']]
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

in settings.js You have basic setting (with all features on):

```
toolbar: [
    ['style', ['style']],
    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']],
    ['table', ['table']],
    ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
    ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
    ['help', ['help']]
  ],
```

indentation is in **'paragraph'**

Comment: This has moved to `src/js/defaults.js` and has slightly changed.

Comment: Is it possible to finetune the `['style', ['style']]` section? Like disable all except `<p>` and `<h5>` tags?? This is needed so the client can't mess up the design while using h1 tags that are not set in Sass.

Comment: To add video:  ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'hr']],

Comment: @NicolasV did you manage to get only <p> and <h5> tags? I also need this.

Comment: @AlexandruComan to manage this use the styleTags option: `// default value is ['p', 'blockquote', 'pre', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']
    styleTags: ['p', 'blockquote', 'pre']`

Comment: Another note: `styleTags` option is a `summernote` option, not a `toolbar` option.

Answer (score 11):

**paragraph** includes **indent** and **outdent**, **codeview** as it suggests does **codeview**.

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
        //[groupname, [button list]]

        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['view', ['codeview']],
    ]
});
```

If you look on the main Summernote website as opposed to the API docs you will see a clear example, that explains how to customise the toolbar. It is on the Deep Dive page and scroll down to Custom Toolbar. It also lists the available toolbar buttons.

http://summernote.org/#/deep-dive#custom-toolbar

Comment: In your toolbar you set `['style', ['bold', 'italic',...` where do you set `h5`tags? Instead of useing ALL the styles like this: `['style', ['style']]`?