# adding some text in the summernote toolbar

Tags: javascript, text, summernote

just wondering if there isan easy way to add some text in the summernote toolbar, on the right side after all the actions buttons. I created a mockup with this image:

[image: mockup]

Thanks a lot

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812825/custom-toolbar-with-summernote

Comment: Thanks. I've already had a look in there, the only custom option I can find is to add custom buttons, which is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to achieve the above just using jQuery and appending a new element with the desidered text.
I was hoping though there was a way using the Summernote libray